# Testing based on roles and permissions based website

Tags: testing, drupal, automated-tests, drupal-8

What would be the best approach or the best tool for testing a drupal based website that deals mainly with roles and permissions? Just an insight. I am currently thinking about behat being the best tool in order to do the testing on such a website. but any other suggestions? any other insights on the topic. 
its a website that builds another website or an intranet service. different types of roles are assigned different types of permissions in order to perform the build. behat still the best approach for automated testing or any other tool would help. behat is one of the best toold for drupal based websites, my question is more specific only because it involves a lot of users haveing various different roles and permissions. 
thank you world :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from

> lot of users haveing various different roles and permissions

you most likely have your [Roles & Permissions Matrix](https://businessanalystlearnings.com/ba-techniques/2018/1/12/roles-permissions-matrix) cleared out. Once there is unambiguous and shared understanding around it, I would suggest to look at [Persona based testing](https://medium.com/@ChamalAsela/persona-based-testing-de6e1396c23c) as it

> is a fictional character/user profile created to represent a user type that might use a product/or a service in a similar way

In combination with the [Touring heuristic](https://www.michaeldkelly.com/blog/2005/9/20/touring-heuristic.html) should cover most of your UAT ideas/missions.

As to tools, BDD with Behat ot not, it is important to follow the shared process of collaboration on the software development. Post-implementation of features is not the

> idea about how software development should be managed by both business interests and technical insight

It is practical that your [Test harness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness) stack is shared along the team members, but not mandatory IMHO.

Comment: Thank you. that was really helpful